# ¿Por qué no se actualiza mi Database automáticamente? (Firebase)

Tags: java, android, firebase

Tengo que salir y volver a entrar en la `activity` para que se recargue.

Si edito un valor si se cambia automáticamente, pero si borro un `item` complero de mi `CardView` desde la consola de *firebase*, tengo que cerrar la `activity` y volver a abrir, ¿Por qué ocurre esto?

Dejo aquí mi código:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public RecyclerView recyclerListView;
    public  UserAdapter myAdapter;
    public  static TextView textViewEmptyView;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        textViewEmptyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEmptyView);
        recyclerListView=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recylerview_list);
        recyclerListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        myAdapter= new UserAdapter(this);
        recyclerListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        updateAdapter();
    }

    public void updateAdapter(){

        final List<User> listUsers= new ArrayList<>();
        databaseReference.child("Prueba").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                listUsers.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class));
                displayUsers(listUsers);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                updateAdapter();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    //display the user on Adapter
    public void displayUsers(List<User> ls){

        textViewEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        recyclerListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        myAdapter.setData(ls);
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solución.

Creas un método para que te vuelva a recargar el `layout`, como por ejemplo:

```
public void RecargarLayouts(){

        textViewEmptyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEmptyView);
        recyclerListView=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recylerview_list);
        recyclerListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        myAdapter= new UserAdapter(this);
        recyclerListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        updateAdapter();
    }
```

Y lo llamas desde

```
@Override
public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
RecargarLayouts();
}
```

Listo! Ya se actualizará tu `CardView` hacer algún cambio en la *database* desde la consola.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que ocurre es que firebase se suscribe a eventos que escucha del servidor. Es decir cada que cambia algo te notifica del cambio. En tu caso funciona la primera vez por que en tu codigo lo tienes suscrito cuando se agrega un item.

Te explico todos los casos para que tengas idea.

Este ocurre cuando se agrega un item

```
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            listUsers.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class));
            displayUsers(listUsers);

        }
```

Este ocurre cuando cambia un item

```
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            updateAdapter();
        }
```

Este ocurre cuando se remueve un item. Aqui te recomiendo hacer la lógica de remover y repintar tu adapter. Ya sea que lo quites de tu ListUsers o repintes todo por completo. Depende de lo que haga tu app.

```
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }
```

Este ocurre cuando se mueve de lugar un item

```
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }
```

Comment: Justo acababa de poner la solución, pero te marco la respuesta como la correcta para no ponérmela a mi misma. Gracias por tu respuesta! @ArturoJamaica , cree una pregunta nueva aquí, mírala si puedes, por favor, gracias! https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/72200/es-posible-recibir-una-notificaci%C3%B3n-al-actualizar-la-base-de-datos-en-firebase