# ¿Es posible recibir una notificación automática cuando se añada algo en la base de datos de Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

¿Es posible que cuando se añada algo en la `database` que tengo en **Firebase** reciba una notificación automática en mi aplicación?

Comment: La misma persona que realiza las modificaciones genere una notiicac´n?

Comment: Que se genere automáticamente la notificación. Cuando se haya añadido algo nuevo o alguna modificación en la base de datos. Se envíe una notificación @Jorgesys

Comment: Podrías ayudarme? @Jorgesys

Comment: Facil, haz la aplicacion que obtenga datos del main de tu base de datos y en ves de utilizar los datos, solo utilizas el listener para crear la notificación.

Comment: Podrías añadir una respuesta con un ejemplo de lo que me comentas? Gracias @EduardoRicardez !

Comment: La estoy haciendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference referenciaPersonaAgregada = database.getReference("personaAgregada");
Button btnAgregarPersona;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Servicio.class);
    startService(intent);

    btnAgregarPersona = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btnAgregarPersona.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Random id = new Random();
            //Donde quiero guardar las personas
            DatabaseReference referenciaPersonas = database.getReference("personas");
            //Lleno un objeto con los datos que metere adentro del nodo adentro de personas
            Persona persona= new Persona(""+id.nextInt(),"Pancho","Rodriguez","Panchito");
            //envio el objeto a firebase
            referenciaPersonas.push().setValue(persona);;
            //envio el objeto tambien a la referencia personaAgregada
            referenciaPersonaAgregada.setValue(persona);
        }
    });


}
```

}

```
public class Servicio extends Service {
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference referenciaPersonaAgregada = database.getReference("personaAgregada");
String datosFirebase = "";
String datosFirebaseCopia = "";
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String manufacturer = "xiaomi";
    if(manufacturer.equalsIgnoreCase(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER)) {
        //this will open auto start screen where user can enable permission for your app
        Intent intent2 = new Intent();
        intent2.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
        intent2.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent2);
    }

    referenciaPersonaAgregada.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Guardo en un HashMap todos los datos de la base de datos valgase la redundancia de Firebase.
            datosFirebase = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());

            if (datosFirebase==null){
                datosFirebase="";
            }

            //Si el clon esta vacio (Obviamente estara vacio la primera vez) haz una copia de lo primero que ha cogido de la base de datos.
            if (datosFirebaseCopia.isEmpty()) {

                datosFirebaseCopia = datosFirebase;

            }
            //Si ambas son iguales, nada ha cambiado ( La primera vez obviamente nada ha cambiado)
            if (datosFirebase.equals(datosFirebaseCopia)) {
                Log.d("TEST", "Hey hola, ¿Que has hecho? , vengo de revisar la base de datos ¿Y que crees? , no hay nada nuevo... sin cambios, no cambia, no madura,no crece la" +
                        "base de datos.");
            }
            //Pero si la segunda vez que cheque si son iguales y no lo son, es que la base de datos ha cambiado
            else {
                //Ahora si, echame la notificaciooon!
                //Notificación , nada sorprendente.
                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
                NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                int icono = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, intent, 0);

                mBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setSmallIcon(icono)
                        .setContentTitle("Firebase")
                        .setContentText("Oyes, acaba de cambiar la base de datos , te aviso nadamas por si querias saber ¿no?")
                        .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 250, 100, 500})
                        .setAutoCancel(true);

                mNotifyMgr.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
                //-------------Fin del codigo notificacion.

                datosFirebaseCopia = datosFirebase;
            }

            //Los valores de la base de datos, digo, por si los quieres ver , ¿Para que? , pues para nada, te ayuda a comprender un poco que se esta haciendo viendo algo graficamente, yo digo, ¿No? .-. .
            Log.d("TEST", "Value is: " + datosFirebase);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w("TEST", "No funciono mi idea >.<", error.toException());
        }
    });

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Log.e("FLAGX : ", ServiceInfo.FLAG_STOP_WITH_TASK + "");
    Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            this.getClass());
    restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

    PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
            getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
            restartServicePendingIntent);

    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}
```

}

```
public class Persona {
String id;
String nombre;
String apellido;
String alias;

public Persona(String id, String nombre, String apellido, String alias) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.alias = alias;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}

public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}

public String getAlias() {
    return alias;
}

public void setAlias(String alias) {
    this.alias = alias;
}
```

}

Copia y pega en cada clase. Te funcionara aunque cierres la aplicacion, no tiene inicio al arrancar el telefono y funcionara perfecto, pero si no tienes internet, perderas el mensaje, pero hay otras soluciones para eso.

Comment: Mil gracias! Esta todo perfectamente explicado en cada parte del código, gracias!! :D

Answer (score -1):

Si es posible usando las nuevas Firebase Cloud Funtions. Necesitas hacerlas principalmente usando firebase-tools.

En lo que consiste es que suscribes una url que machea a tu url de tu arbol de json y ejecutas una función que asu vez puede interactuar con el GCM.

Te recomiendo que hagas este tutorial para entender las cloud functions https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-cloud-functions/#0

Esta es tu respuesta tal cual : https://aaronczichon.de/2017/03/13/firebase-cloud-functions/