# ¿Como puedo hacer que mi app lea Realtime Database de Firebase y lanzar una notificación cuando está cerrada?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, realtime-database

Estoy realizando una app que necesito que reciba notificaciones al realizar cambios en la BBDD. He usado una solución de 2017 pero no me funciona:

[¿Es posible recibir una notificación automática cuando se añada algo en la base de datos de Firebase?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/72200/es-posible-recibir-una-notificaci%C3%B3n-autom%C3%A1tica-cuando-se-a%C3%B1ada-algo-en-la-base?newreg=59deb05582d2456b8e31554d1b4e911a)

Funciona si la app esta en segundo plano pero si la cierro no recibo notificaciones.

El resto de la app funciona correctamente.

No consigo solucionar este problema, cualquier ayuda se agradece. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Si con recibir notificaciones te refieres a que la app sincronice los datos que muestra en pantalla con la bbdd de forma inmediata(realtime) entonces debes asegurarte de consultar las referencias de firebase adecuadas.
Sin ver tu código no estoy seguro de que podamos ayudarte pero igual te puede servir de ayuda este proyecto que funciona y sincroniza los datos: https://github.com/rcAndroidTutorials/example-firebase/tree/master

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución pero recuerda realizar respuestas en base a [answer],saludos.

Comment: Gracias por responderme, la aplicación se sincroniza perfectamente, mi problema viene al intentar hacer una clase-servicio que extiende de Service, he adjuntado el enlace de una pregunta similar ya contestada pero que a mi no me funciona.

Comment: Hola @David, sin ver algo de tu código es difícil ofrecer una respuesta mejor.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por la ayuda. Acabo de añadir mi código para ver si consigo solucionar el problema.